# Find strings in multiple files and give count per file

Tags: parsing, powershell, logfile

I'm using PowerShell to look at IIS logs and I need to get a count on 500 errors per log file.

I've used :

```
dir $logpath -recursive | select-string -pattern ' 500 ' | measure-object
```

but this gets me the total count for all files. I need the count for each file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

select-String matches expose a Path property which you can use to group by:

```
dir $logpath -recursive | select-string -pattern ' 500 ' | group path
```

Comment: The default formatting cuts off the count (auto-format table), so I had to add `| ft Count,Name`

Comment: i.e. `| group path | ft Count,Name`